# Was “drama queen” a gay slang expression originally?

Tags: phrase-origin

According to Greens Dictionary of Slang the expression  ***[drama queen](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/rzieapa)*** is a from gay slang and dates to the early nineties.

> (orig. gay) anyone considered to be making an excessive fuss or ‘making a mountain out of a molehill’;
>
> - 1991    [US]    D. Gaines Teenage Wasteland 71: Joe was very intense, a real drama queen.

Actually earlier usages appear to have a different connotation, such as the following from 
Rock singer Marianne Faifhfull who used the expression in a interview on  ***[Billboard](https://books.google.it/books?id=GyQEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT15&dq=%22drama%20queen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimjYGp0Y3mAhWJjqQKHd8WBrI4ChDoAQhHMAY#v=onepage&q=%22drama%20queen%22&f=false)***  some ten years earlier:  (Oct 17, 1981)

> “That root of anger and sorrow was exorcised”,  she continues "This is a bit of affirmation I didn't want to be known as the great drama queen of rock'n'roll, though I could have been”.

and the website [wordsmith.org](https://ETYMOLOGY:%20From%20Greek%20drama%20(action,%20play)%20+%20Old%20English%20cwen%20(woman,%20queen).%20Earliest%20documented%20use:%201923.) suggests a much earlier origin:

> From Greek drama (action, play) + Old English cwen (woman, queen). Earliest documented use: 1923.

but I couldn’t  find examples of such early usages.

Was the expression from gay slang or was it originally a theatrical expression which was later adopted by the gay community with the current connotation?

Comment: Per Ngram, the earliest common usage appears to have been in the title of a series of books.

Answer (score 4):

The 1923 date comes from the OED, citing a Washington Post article:

> If he is thwarted in his effort to enjoy them, he may either go to the dogs or the drama queens, become short-tempered, sullen, grouchy and eventually feel that, in a way he is a failure.

This [article](https://books.google.com/books?id=YCJbAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA4-PA58&lpg=RA4-PA58&dq=If%20he%20is%20thwarted%20in%20his%20effort%20to%20enjoy%20them,%20he%20may%20either%20go%20to%20the%20dogs%20or%20the%20drama%20queens,%20become%20short-tempered,%20sullen,%20grouchy%20and%20eventually%20feel%20that,%20in%20a%20way%20he%20is%20a%20failure.&source=bl&ots=Buyqh8Xz4t&sig=ACfU3U3NJvcXmTGTBxtDd2mp68jTrusB9g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ3vKw_I3mAhVJq1kKHe-UBdkQ6AEwAXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=If%20he%20is%20thwarted%20in%20his%20effort%20to%20enjoy%20them%2C%20he%20may%20either%20go%20to%20the%20dogs%20or%20the%20drama%20queens%2C%20become%20short-tempered%2C%20sullen%2C%20grouchy%20and%20eventually%20feel%20that%2C%20in%20a%20way%20he%20is%20a%20failure.&f=false) is about man caves, and is actually very heteronormative (as one would expect for this time period).

What about gay usage specifically? Well, I’m still looking into this, but I did find an example from in an article called *Positive Thoughts on [C.H.E.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_for_Homosexual_Equality)* (published in *Lunch* in London, 1972) by gay author Chris Brooks:

> A number of gays would like to work full-time for CHE or other homophile organizations. They are at best potential martyrs, and at worst drama queens.

I also found an article called *The Adventures of Super Gay: Part III — in Hot (and Sweaty) Pursuit* (published in [*Gay News*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_News) in London, 1974), which is a gay parody of superheroes:

> "We're all behind you, Super-Gay."
>
> In minutes, they had arrived outside 'Bona Mops' [the employment agency] and they both dashed in contriving as they did so to knock over a pottled  palm and a tall thin man with a filleted  wrist.
>
> "Drama queens! That's all I need, drama queens!"

Comment: But "drama queen" in the gay sense is clearly a pun on the original usage.

Comment: Actually early usages, prior to gay slag, are quite rare. So what was the sense originally? Sort of primadonna?

Comment: I've heard the expression _tragedy queen_ too (see https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tragedy_queen ). It means a woman who enjoys behaving like the heroine of a melodrama.

Comment: @KateBunting  What I was trying to find out is if “drama queen” was mainly used humorously even before the gay slang. And it probably was.

Answer (score 2):

My mother often used to use this phrase to describe someone who was over-dramatising a situation. Born in 1928, she grew up in wartime London. I wonder whether the phrase came out of the music halls (as did a lot of her songs and references). Possibly linked to Poloni?

Comment: Did you mean [Polari](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/staff/bakerjp/polari/home.htm)?